# How do I filter through an associated resource column using a named_scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, named-scope

I have built a Ruby on Rails application that allows users to track their workouts.

`User has_many :workouts`

`Workout belongs_to :user`

I am attempting to call only workouts from male users. How do I write a named scope for `Workout.rb` to call only workouts from male users?

In my case, the user.sex column is a string that collects either `Male` or `Female`.

I am using rails 2.3.8 for this particular application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Workout

  belongs_to :user
  named_scope :all_male,   :joins => :user, 
                           :conditions => ["users.sex = ?", "Male"]

  named_scope :all_female, :joins => :user, 
                           :conditions => ["users.sex = ?", "Female"]

end
```

Now you can use the scope as:

```
Workout.all_male    
Workout.all_female
```

Comment: beautiful, thank you. Good to run into you again KandadaBoggu. You've been a big help to me in the past.